# Button Enable After Correct Input In TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my view I have a `Textbox` and a `Button` **next to it** that is attached to a `Command` that can or cannot execute (making the button enabled or disabled) based on the correct value entered in the textbox.

Everything works fine, except of the fact that after the user enters a correct value and presses TAB the focus does not move to the specified button but to the control after it, although that the button gets enabled correctly.

In other words the UI isn't fast enough after the TAB pressed to enable the button and got the focus. Instead the button is enabled but after the focus has already been moved to the other control.

The `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `TextBox` binding is `LostFocus` and I would like to have it like that since a lot of things happen to have it `PropertyChanged` for every single character the user inputs.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: please see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088393/enable-button-on-valid-textbox solves it.

Comment: thanks for the interest... I already show this question. It might be a solution if I don't solve this having the button control its behavior just based on the CanExecute of the command. CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() unfortunately does not work...

Comment: Have you tried set the updatesourcetrigger to propertychanged?

Comment: @MiklósBalogh Yes, and it works. But my textbox uses a converter  to fix its value and such converters does not work correctly with PropertyChanged. That's why I said I would like not to use PropertyChanged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came to a solution without destroying too much the MVVM pattern that I use (referring to specific controls with specific names).

What I did is to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` instead of `LostFocus`. The problem with `PropertyChanged` was that my `ValueConverter` was not running anymore. So although the button now gets enabled or disabled correctly and right on time to be ready for receiving the focus, the displayed value in my textbox was not ok.

I solved that by listening to textbox's `LostFocus` event and there using `BindingExpression.UpdateTarget()` my `TextBox.Text` appears now correctly.

Here it is:

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding Path=SpecialText, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus">
</TextBox>


private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you have a couple of options:

1. Use `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` instead of `LostFocus` and attach your own `LostFocus` handler that both updates the binding and also sets focus on your button if relevant.
2. Attach your own `LostFocus` handler that checks whether the text is valid and, if so, sets focus back on the button.

In both cases, you may need to perform the set focus in a separate dispatcher message:

```
private void OnLostFocus(...)
{
    if (textIsValid)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)() => button.Focus());
    }
}
```